# How to push a local repository in GitHub to a remote one using PyCharm

Tags: github, pycharm

I use PyCharm with GitHub and I have a local repository called "Final_Code_v1". I would like to push it to the remote repository such that I can access it via the GitHub webinterface. Here is a screenshot of my repository structure

[image]

I tried it via Right-Click and then Push but this does not create a repository in the GitHub webinterface and it does not move the "Final_Code_v1" repository to the Remote repositories in PyCharm. I just get the message that everything is up to date but nothing changes.

Comment: One way is to initially create a repo in GitHub directly using GitHub webinterface. You can then go to your current PyCharm Project directory and open the file **config** in the hidden **.git** folder. The setting **url** in the group '[remote "origin"]' is then containing your repository link such as 'https://github.com/yourproject'

Comment: I just saw that you should also be able to manage this via PyCharm by using the following menu:
**Top Menu bar->Git->Manage Remotes...->Add**
But I guess you will also have to create the repo on GitHub first and copy the URL

Comment: @Jensolo: Thanks for your comments. Acutally I would like PyCharm to create the repository automatically just by a command. I think this should be possible. I already of course have a superordinate repository, that contains the branches listed in the screenshot under "Remote". My question is how can I move my new local branch "Final_Code_v1" into the "Remote" branches and thus into the GitHub respository

Comment: Ok, I see. I just checked PyCharm documentation and it looks like you are looking for the function **Share a Project on GitHub** as explained in this doc article:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html#share-on-GitHub
Hope this helps!